# Javascript "this" issue

Tags: javascript, this

I'm new to Javascript and trying to figure out why console.log isn't printing out the name of the User.  I want the function NewUser to take the new Variable (Emily and Jason) and print out their names along with their "life".

My problem seems to be the line "this.name="" ", I don't know how to get this.name to take in the name of the variable for the newuser.  I've tried this.name; but that returned undefined.

```
function NewUser(){
    this.name="";
    this.life=100;
    this.mana=1000;

    console.log(this.life);
    console.log(this.name);

}


var Jason=new NewUser();
Jason.name="Jason";
var Emily=new NewUser();
Emily.name="Emily";
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you already have?  It looks like it would work.  Probably better to pass the initial name as an argument to the constructor, but what you have should also work.

Comment: The `console.log()` statements are currently inside of the constructor (which runs when you call `new NewUser()`. You're not setting the `name` property until *after* that, though.

Comment: search Stackoverflow using '[javascript] this': **1,309,289** results

Comment: @KooiInc this isn't actually a problem with using `this`. The problem is just order of execution. OP's references to `this.name` and `SomeUser.name` are all correct... (just ordered wrong).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the feedback!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add a parameter to your function, like the following:

```
function NewUser(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.life=100;
    this.mana=1000;
    console.log(this.life);
    console.log(this.name);
}

var Jason=new NewUser("Jason");
var Emily=new NewUser("Emily");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the console.log statement is being executed when you call the constructor function, at which point the name variable is an empty string.

```
var Jason=new NewUser(); // console.log called here
Jason.name="Jason";
var Emily=new NewUser(); // console.log called here
Emily.name="Emily";
```

to fix this, try passing the user name into the function:

```
function NewUser(username){
    this.name=username;
    this.life=100;
    this.mana=1000;

    console.log(this.life);
    console.log(this.name);

}


var Jason=new NewUser("Jason");
var Emily=new NewUser("Emily");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading `this.name` before write anything to it.

Another way to do it is to create a `log` function that you can call later. Example:

```
function NewUser(){
    this.name="";
    this.life=100;
    this.mana=1000;

    this.log = function() {
      console.log(this.life);
      console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var Jason=new NewUser();
Jason.name="Jason";
var Emily=new NewUser();
Emily.name="Emily";
Jason.log();
Emily.log();
```